# Exception when trying to load an XML resource

Tags: android, f#, xamarin.android

I've taken the Xamarin OpenGL example application for F# and am trying to load (mesh) data from an XML. I've added the XML file to `Resources/values` and set its Build Action to `AndroidResource` but I get an exception when I try to read it.

I'm using this F# code to try to read the file:

```
context.Resources.GetXml Resource_String.n
```

where `context` is an object of the type `MainActivity` passed into `GLView1`.

The exception I get is:

```
08-03 12:18:23.931 V/GLCube  (29315): *****   at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallObjectMethod (IntPtr jobject, IntPtr jmethod, Android.Runtime.JValue[] parms) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

08-03 12:18:23.931 V/GLCube  (29315):   at Android.Content.Res.Resources.GetXml (Int32 id) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

08-03 12:18:23.931 V/GLCube  (29315):   at AndroidOpenGLFSharp.GLView1..ctor (AndroidOpenGLFSharp.MainActivity context) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

08-03 12:18:23.931 V/GLCube  (29315):   --- End of managed exception stack trace ---

08-03 12:18:23.931 V/GLCube  (29315): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File 8 from xml type xml resource ID #0x7f040000

08-03 12:18:23.931 V/GLCube  (29315):   at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2351)

08-03 12:18:23.931 V/GLCube  (29315):   at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2306)

08-03 12:18:23.931 V/GLCube  (29315):   at android.content.res.Resources.getXml(Resources.java:983)

08-03 12:18:23.931 V/GLCube  (29315):   at androidopenglfsharp.MainActivity.n_onCreate(Native Method)

08-03 12:18:23.931 V/GLCube  (29315):   at androidopenglfsharp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:30)

08-03 12:18:23.931 V/GLCube  (29315):   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)

08-03 12:18:23.931 V/GLCube  (29315):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)

08-03 12:18:23.931 V/GLCube  (29315):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)

08-03 12:18:23.931 V/GLCube  (29315):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)

08-03 12:18:23.931 V/GLCube  (29315):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)

08-03 12:18:23.931 V/GLCube  (29315):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)

08-03 12:18:23.931 V/GLCube  (29315):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

08-03 12:18:23.931 V/GLCube  (29315):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

08-03 12:18:23.931 V/GLCube  (29315):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)

08-03 12:18:23.931 V/GLCube  (29315):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

08-03 12:18:23.931 V/GLCube  (29315):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)

08-03 12:18:23.931 V/GLCube  (29315):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)

08-03 12:18:23.931 V/GLCube  (29315):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)

08-03 12:18:23.931 V/GLCube  (29315):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

08-03 12:18:23.931 V/GLCube  (29315): Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: 8

08-03 12:18:23.931 V/GLCube  (29315):   at android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlAssetNative(Native Method)

08-03 12:18:23.931 V/GLCube  (29315):   at android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlBlockAsset(AssetManager.java:488)

08-03 12:18:23.931 V/GLCube  (29315):   at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2333)

08-03 12:18:23.931 V/GLCube  (29315):   ... 18 more

08-03 12:18:24.001 V/PhoneStatusBar( 1201): setLightsOn(true)

08-03 12:18:24.021 V/GLCube  (29315): Loading with default settings
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should load xml like this.

```
    SpannableString text = new SpannableString(getResources().getString(
            R.string.aboutus));
```

i hope this will work.